# Which step is correct when we evaluate Limit

Tags: limits, continuity

*Let a function be f (x) = x and we have to check its continuity at x = 0.*

I have evaluted both sides limit but I have a doubt whether 1 is correct or 2 is  correct in the below image.

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think 1 is correct because in second, you have removed minus sign, which means the limit is not longer remain one sided.

Comment: @HardeyPandya Will the things change  is f (x) = |x| ?

Comment: I did't understand that in which context you are asking ?

Comment: @HardeyPandya For f (x) = x you said 1 is correct. I want to know if f (x) = |x| is another function then which one will be  correct. Or 1 will be correct independent of the given function.